# Binding JavaScript Variables to HTML Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I've got this system whereby a Bootstrap table is created. In each cell in the each row, a numerical value appears representing the number of, say, customers in that region. Something like,

```
-----------------------------------
     Region     |     Number
-----------------------------------
New York        |        5
New England     |        8
Florida         |        3
-----------------------------------
```

The number is calculated in JavaScript when the DOM loads. The JavaScript receives all customers in an unorganized array, which I then sorted out into a proper matrix called customers[region], where each element in customers is itself an array of objects, like this:

```
var customers = {
   0 : ["customer1","customer2","customer3"],
   1 : ["customer4","customer5","customer6"],
   2 : ["customer7","customer8","customer9"]
}
```

The table cells are filled in dynamically with some JS code looking like

```
var cell = "<td><a id='testLink0' href='#'>" + customers[0].length + "</a></td>"
$("#row1").append(string); // Gets one of the rows, and appends to it
```

Now, however, I want to load a modal window when the user clicks one of the numbers. The modal window will show a table of all of the customers in that region. I am able to turn each of the numbers into a link that opens the modal window, but I can't find a good way to pass the modal window the data. So I want to bind customers[0] to one link, bind customers[1] to another link, etc, so that when the link is clicked, the modal window receives that specific JavaScript object.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a#testLink0').click(function(e) {
        $.get('template.html', function(data){
            modal.open({content: data});
    });
});
```

How can I pass the JavaScript object to some JavaScritp code in template.html? Note that the number of links is actually much, much greater, so much greater that it would be best to assign the links dynamically. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a better approach simply to generate the ids (or any other attributes of those links) dynamically but in a way that you're able to map the given generated attribute value (for instance an id of `customers1`) to the hash key of your object connected to that link (`customers1` would lead you to the key `1` in your hash, for instance) so you're able to get that attribute value from the click `event` -> `e` (by examining the value of `e.target` - http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) passed to your `.click(function(e) {...})`and then simply read the hash property you want to populate your modal.

Comment: I am sort of doing this in a way, mapping each link to an object dynamically. And I can read the clicked link from the event. However, the actual value that the key points to is not passed. The actual data. I'm able to get the modal window up and have it figure out which link was clicked on, based on the event. But I can't figure out a way to pass it the actual data other than by URL params, which has a character limit. The name or the ID of the link that was clicked isn't the main data, it's just a pointer to the data.

Comment: I realize that, so it's a matter of making your hash variable available to the modal logic so it can fetch the appropriate property based on the key perceived from the event.